# Proving that $\mathbb{C}$ has a natural definition

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-numbers, hypercomplex-numbers

I would like to prove a theorem in complex analysis which states:

> Let $K$ be a commutative field. We suppose that $L$ is a sub-field of $K$ and that $K$ is thus a vector space of finite dimension $n$ over $L$.
>
> Then, either $n=1$ and $K=L$, or $n=2$ and $K$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$. If there is no restriction on $K$ being commutative, you obtain the field of quaternions for $n=4$.

1. Beyond the definition of the complex field as such, I can't understand why it can't be possible to define a complex field isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ for all $n$ if one defines a multiplication law for each $n$ and thus build a corresponding ring and then a field for each $n$. Why is it not possible to define such a multiplication rule?
2. Can somebody give me some hints how to prove the theorem?

Thanks for any comment.

Answer (score 3):

As written, strictly speaking, your theorem is false. You need to add the additional requirement that $L = \Bbb R$. Your statement then becomes:

What field extensions of finite degree of the real numbers can we obtain?

The usual approach is to do this:

1) Show that if $K$ is a finite extension of $\Bbb R$ it is an *algebraic* extension of $\Bbb R$.

2) Show that any finite field extension of $\Bbb R$ can be realized as a (ring) isomorph of a quotient $\Bbb R[x]/\langle f(x)\rangle$, where $f$ is an irreducible polynomial in $\Bbb R[x]$.

3) Use the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra (this is where complex analysis typically comes into play-in proving the FTOA, using Liouville's Theorem) to show that the only irreducible polynomials in $\Bbb R[x]$ are of degree $1$ or $2$.

4) Show that if $[K:\Bbb R] = 2$, then $K$ contains a root $j$ of $x^2 + 1$ (hint: use the quadratic formula to produce this root from the discriminant of your irreducible quadratic).

To answer your other question:

Sir William Rowan Hamilton searched for a *long* time for a way to turn $\Bbb R^3$ into a division algebra over $\Bbb R$. He finally turned instead to $\Bbb R^4$, and discovered the quaternions. In 1877, Ferdinand Georg Frobenius proved Hamilton's search for such a $3$-dimensional division algebra was indeed pointless, which you can read about [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_theorem_%28real_division_algebras%29).

A "hand-wavy" argument as to "why" only powers of two work (up to a point) is that multiplication is desired to be bilinear, and bilinear functions play well with squares, but not other powers. The truth of the matter is a wee bit more complicated, but also beautiful.

Comment: Thanks for your very interesting comment.

Comment: You are saying that only powers of two work. Is it what do you mean ?The theorem is stating that quaterions are the forming the last division algebra on R^n.

Comment: Google "octonions" and "sedenions", in which some of the properties a division algebra must have a relaxed.